# ODOO 11 filter record for HR Recruitment application

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I' a newbie for ODOO. I'm trying to develop my knowledge. Then I make a personal project name "My Recruitment". 
I'v inherited model "hr.applicant" and add new field name "x_place". 
Model "place" has many2many "res.users".

```
   class MYRecruitment(models.Model):
        x_place = fields.Many2one('my.recruitment.place', "Place")


        class MyRecruitmentPlace(models.Model):
            _name = "my.recruitment.place"
            _description = "Place of Recruitment"
            _sql_constraints = [('name_uniq', 'unique (name)', 'The name of the place of Recruitment must be unique!')]

            name = fields.Char("Place", required=True, translate=True)
            user_ids = fields.Many2many('res.users', string="Owners")
            sequence = fields.Integer("Sequence", default=1, help="Gives the sequence order when displaying a list of place.")  



<odoo>  
    <data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="hr_kanban_view_applicant_my_extend">
        <field name="name">Hr Applicants kanban Extend</field>
        <field name="model">hr.applicant</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_recruitment.hr_kanban_view_applicant"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//kanban" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="quick_create">false</attribute>
                <attribute name="default_order">create_date desc</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
    </data> 
</odoo>


Place:
----------------------------------------
Place     User
---------------------------------------
Place01   user1,user2,user3
Place02   user2
Place03   user3
----------------------------------------


Applicant:
----------------------------------------
Name       Place 
----------------------------------------
App1       Place01
App2       Place01
App3       Place02
App4       Place03
-----------------------------------------
```

I'd like the odoo show the record with the following scenario:
When user login

```
user1:   
    show  App1
user2:
    show  App1,App2, App3
user3:
     Show App1,App4
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I dont get it too.